# Can't detect collisions in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I'm new to Unity and struggling to get the `OnCollisionEnter` function to pick up.

I realize this sounds similar to other questions, but I still can't get it to work for my case.

I'm using the Oculus Distance Grab Sample Scene.

I've got a block trying to run into a soccer ball ;)

The block has a box collider (non trigger) and rigid body (non gravity, non kinematic).

The soccer ball has a Sphere Collider (non trigger) and a rigid body (yes gravity, non kinematic).

The block contains a script component that makes it float over to the ball and run into it.

The ball has a script with the OnCollisionEnter function that is supposed to destroy the block upon contact.

Here's the `Player` script attached to the ball.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {
        FloatingItem item = col.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<FloatingItem>();
        Destroy(item);
    }
}
```

The ball is in the `Player` layer and the block in the `Attacker` layer.  I double checked collision were enabled between these layers in the Player Settings collision matrix.

Also, the colliders of each object seem to be the size they should to match the mesh.

Any help to get the collisions working would be wonderful!

Here's a visual of the settings as well:

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Here is the floating block's `Update` method:

```
void FixedUpdate () {
      if(targetTransform != null) {
        this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.transform.position, targetTransform.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
      }
    }
```

I have been trouble getting any debug logs to show in the console so they haven't been reliable.  But the answer was that the collision was in fact working but that I was destroying the wrong object.

Changing it to `Destroy(col.collider.gameObject)` works.  An important distinction learned here!  Thanks!

**UPDATE 2:**

I've added an image of how the `OVRPlayerController` is setup.  Trying to read through the weak documentation about the `character controller` component of this but my understanding is that it contains a capsule collider.

[image]

Comment: Please show in particular the code for `The block contains a script component that makes it float over to the ball and run into it.` Spoiler: Anything having a Rigidbody should only be moved via `MovePosition` within `FixedUpdate` otherwise Physics don't work well. If the block is moved by script you might also want to enable `isKinematic` except it shall react to Physics

Comment: right now you are only destroying the FloatingItem script and not the whole GameObject. Did you check with Debug.Log("collision"); if the collision was triggered?

Comment: @derHugo if you use MovePosition every frame, isKinematic should definitely be on, or it is equivalent to setting rigidbody.position. If you want collisions, you should simply set the velocity on the first frame.

Comment: @LouisGarczynski you wouldn't use it `every frame` though but in fixed time intervals (usually 0.2 seconds)

Comment: As @nka_Zz pointed out I was not destroying the game object correctly.  Now it works when the block collides with the soccer ball.  But this originally came from trying to have the block collide with OVRPlayerController.  It still does not work in that case.  Any thoughts?

Comment: afaik OVRPlayerController has different Collider for hands and body, is the script on the correct GameObject and is the movement towards the correct GameObject? Generally it shouldn't make a difference, since if i remember correctly the hands got a sphere and the body a capsule collider.

Comment: @nka_Zz The OVRPlayerController has a `Character Controller` component which I am fairly sure contains a `capsule collider` though it's not very explicit.  But when the block runs into the OVRPlayerController it just hangs out and doesn't disappear as expected.

Comment: @Frankie you should look at it during debug to see which GameObject holds the Collider

Comment: @derHugo change frame for tick, also a standard tick is usually 0.02 second. Even without that, MovePosition for a non-kinematic object is just setting rigidbody.position. It won't work well with physics nor with interpolation. If you want your object to react to its environment, only use dynamic and AddForce/velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there is a `Rigidbody` involved you should **NOT** set the

```c#
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(...);
```

but rather go through the `Rigidbody` component e.g. using [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

> `Rigidbody.MovePosition` moves a `Rigidbody` and complies with the interpolation settings. When `Rigidbody` interpolation is enabled, `Rigidbody.MovePosition` creates a smooth transition between frames.

This keeps the Physics intact while moving via the `transform.position` creates a hard jump which will not react to collisions!

```c#
// If possible already reference this via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

public Rigidbody target;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    // Always when controlling your position by script the Rigidbody 
    // should be kinematic
    _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
}

private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    _rigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3.MoveTowards(_rigidbody.position, target.position, Time.deltaTime * movespeed));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But `OVRPlayerController` doesn't technically have a `Rigidbody` so I'm not sure what to add as the target.  When I set the target to OVRPlayerController itself, the block does 'collide' with the player but knocks the player into space.  And `OnCollisionEnter` is still not called.  My goal is just to detect the collision via `OnCollisionEnter`.

Comment: I you don't want them to physically collide you probably rather would want to use `OnTriggerEnter` and turn the other collider to a `isTrigger`

Comment: Ugh, yep making it a trigger worked.  I think I get the difference now.  Also, I added a capsule collider to `OVRPlayerController` and got the collisions to work as well.  I never did this before because the documentation here says it's character controller component could be affected by collisions out of the box: https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-sf-distancegrab/

Comment: @Frankie it is possible that it uses some kind of Raycast in order to determine if you can grab something which would not be the same as actual collisions

Comment: you are correct that it uses a separate sphere collider (on a child object of the ovrplayercontroller) as a trigger to detect whether an item is within grab range or not.